# Java Hibernate Check MySQL Replication is in sync

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Normally we check if replication on slaves is working via the console command

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;
```

I would like to incorporate this functionality into a servlet reporting application.
However, hibernate does not seem to allow this :

```
createSQLQuery("SHOW SLAVE STATUS");
...executing query...
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: not yet implemented for SQL queries
```

I'm sure it's possible to achieve this using native JDBC, however maybe there is a better way?
Environment: Linux 2.6.18, Tomcat 6/7,  Hibernate 3.4, Java 1.6, MySQL 5
Note: I'm not interested in solutions where we insert timestamps on master.

Comment: Where exactly you are getting this exception

Comment: refer this link you may get some idea about your problem [Link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2413979). also refer other link from this link

Comment: @PSR java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: not yet implemented for SQL queries
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.getReturnTypes(SQLQueryImpl.java:249)
 com.xxxxxx.servlet.doGet(AbstractServlet.java:516)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me..

```
SQLQuery query =session.createSQLQuery("show slave status");
ArrayList<Object[]> results = (ArrayList<Object[]>)query.list();
//there is only one row returned
Object [] result =  results.get(0);
//Seconds Behind Master should always be the last value in the row.
String secondsBehindMaster = ""+result[result.length-1];
```

Ensure DB user has REPLICATION CLIENT permission to make this query.

```
GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'db_server' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_password';
```

Comment: Seems so Simple. I think the permissions was also a factor. It now works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `createSQLQuery` to run a native SQL query, you have to tell Hibernate [how to convert the results into Java objects](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-2/api/net/sf/hibernate/Criteria.html#ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).  The easiest way in your case is to add

```
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
```

to the query before executing it. (If the query returned already-mapped Entities, you could just use `addEntity()`.)

Comment: If this doesn't work then you need to provide more information about what you are doing and what is causing the exception. `...executing query...` is not very informative.

Comment: Somebody edited my question - apologies if they made it less informative.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried hard enough to make this work with Hibernate, but if that fails, you can still use a good old-fashioned JDBC connection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {

    static final String DB_ADDRESS = "localhost";
    static final String DB_NAME = "mysql";
    static final String DB_USER = "root";

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // get password
        String password = "";
        if (args!=null && args.length>0) {
            password = args[0];
        }

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle the error
            System.out.println("Driver issue: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Driver issue: " + ex.getClass().toString());
        }
        // connect to database
        try {
            Connection conn = 
               DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+DB_ADDRESS+"/"+DB_NAME+"?autoReconnect=true",DB_USER,password);

            // Do something with the Connection
            System.out.println("Connection: " + conn);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();


            ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");
            while (RS.next()) {
                System.out.println("table: '" + RS.getString(1) + "'");
            }

            // disconnect from database
            conn.close();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
}
```

This would return:

```
Connection: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@528acf6e
table: 'columns_priv'
table: 'db'
table: 'event'
table: 'func'
table: 'general_log'
table: 'help_category'
table: 'help_keyword'
table: 'help_relation'
table: 'help_topic'
table: 'host'
table: 'ndb_binlog_index'
table: 'plugin'
table: 'proc'
table: 'procs_priv'
table: 'proxies_priv'
table: 'servers'
table: 'slow_log'
table: 'tables_priv'
table: 'time_zone'
table: 'time_zone_leap_second'
table: 'time_zone_name'
table: 'time_zone_transition'
table: 'time_zone_transition_type'
table: 'user'
```

Needless to say, the key thing is to ensure your user has sufficient privileges.

Answer (score 2):

As the message of the `UnsupportedOperationException` exception suggests, `getReturnTypes()` is not implemented by the `SQLQuery` object returned by `createSQLQuery()`.

By the way, the phrasing of your question is misleading, you do not receive the exception on calling `createSQLQuery()`, but a few lines later.

When you issue native SQL, you will retrieve rows as a list of generic `Object[]` (unless you explicitely provide Hibernate with a mapping). Typically, the types will be known at compile-time.

See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#d5e8250) for more information.