# JDBC returning empty result set on server

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I've got a little problem when I'm running my query.

This is my code:

```
try {
    // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle the error
    System.out.println("Driver issue: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Driver issue: " + ex.getClass().toString());
}

try {
    // Do something with the Connection
    System.out.println("Connection: " + conn);

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery("show slave status");
    ...

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + internetPort + ":" + port + "/", username, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to: " + internetPort);
        return;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
```

I realized that the script is connecting to DB, then execute query but the result is empty. When I'm doing the same query on mysql console then I got 1 result (correct result) I've even changed query "show slave status" to "show processlist" and still nothing. What's more, on my PC it's working correctly and executing query with correct result, but on other PC it doesn't. user and password is correct (the same i logged in console). Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you tell the permission and ownership of MySQL binary logs?

Comment: Are you sure you committed the data, are you sure you are connecting to the same database (BTW: Your code doesn't show connection creation). Also, you should **not** call `DriverManager.registerDriver` in your code. That method is only to be used by JDBC drivers to register themselves when they get loaded.

Comment: Could you explain it a little more? 
Do you mean the credentials i'm trying to log in into mysql? (root)

Comment: `show slave status` is an admin command. I can't see how you could possibly execute that with `executeQuery()` which should be used for `SELECT` SQL statements. Maybe you could get it to work with `stmt.execute("show slave status");`?

Comment: I run the script on my local PC and it's working, we prepared in job an example 2 servers that this script would work on and it worked too. When i'm trying now run it on client i got empty result set. Yes i'm connecting to right DB, every query i've tried got empty RS

Comment: Maybe the query should work after all. At least [someone got it to work even with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788447/java-hibernate-check-mysql-replication-is-in-sync). Maybe it's a permission issue (`REPLICATION CLIENT` on the user you're connecting with).

Comment: I've edited the article, and i added my conn statement. (It's in another method and it running before Execution statement)

Comment: so long story short, i should test it on creating example user with enough privileges to do it right?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Do you think, that user: "root" does not have enough privileges to do that?